Deserialize Map<Enum<?>, Object> in Java with Jackson library
I need to serialize and deserialize in JSON format a Java map using the Jackson library.
The map type is Map<Enum<?>, Object> and its purpose is to store a configuration made by key-value pairs, where keys are enum instances coming from a third party library (hence I do not have control over their definition).
Keys can be enums of different type, whereas values can be int, double or String.
Also, you can assume that different enums have different instance names.
Serialization works fine:
public class Main {
  public enum IntParam {I1, I2, I3}
  public enum DoubleParam {D1, D2, D3}
  public enum StringParam {S1, S2, S3}

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Map<Enum<?>, Object> config = Map.of(
        IntParam.I1, 0, 
        DoubleParam.D2, 1.0, 
        StringParam.S3, "sss"
    );
    new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(config)
    // {"I1": 1, "D2": 1.0, "S3": "sss"} 
  }

The problem is deserializing the above object:
    String json = "{\"I1\": 1, \"D2\": 1.0, \"S3\": \"sss\"}";
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<Enum<?>, Object>>())

fails because Jackson cannot know which enum contains instances named I1, D2 and S3.
I would like to achieve something like
{
   "com.external.company.IntParam.I1": 1,
   "com.external.company.DoubleParam.D2": 1.0,
   "com.external.company.StringParam.S3": "sss"
}

during serialization and then be able to deserialize it.

json-api

Sorry, but I cannot add a dependency just to do this, do you have a smaller workaround?

You can test it locally. I am planning to finish last tests this week and add to maven next week.

Does your library require to annotate the involved enums? In my case they come from a third party library and I have no control over them.

Interesting case. I will add it as a test to the api

How are you going to use this map once you've parsed it? It seems like a weird use case

I am gonna pass the key-value pairs to the same third party library from which the enums come from. Basically, I just need to save the configuration values in a file and then reload them.

What about the values for the map? How are you going to parse Object to a java type? I think you might end up using Map<String, String>

Since values are either int, double or String, Jackson should parse them for me and return an object with type Map<Enum<?>, Object>. If each map entry were an instance of the correct enum type, I could use this information to cast the corresponding value to the correct type.

Are the enums even needed? Jackson will figure out the types of values in the map on its own (since they are built-in types), 0 will be deserialized to Integer, 1.0 to Double and "sss" to String.

Enums are there because I need them when calling other methods of the external library, e.g. externalLibObj.setOption(StringParam.S3, "sss"). Calling enum types by the name of the type of value they hold is just a choice for the simplified example.

Starting from @Chaosfire answer, I achieved exactly what I need.
Code:
  @JsonSerialize(keyUsing=MyEnumSerializer.class)
  @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing=MyEnumDeserializer.class)
  public static class MyParamMap extends HashMap<Enum<?>, Object> {};

  public static class MyEnumSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Enum<?>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(final Enum<?> value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
      gen.writeFieldName(value.getClass().getName() + "." + value.name());
    }
  }

  public static class MyEnumDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(final String key, final DeserializationContext ctxt) {
      final int index = key.lastIndexOf(".");
      final String className = key.substring(0, index);
      try {
        final Class<Enum> enumClass = (Class<Enum>) Class.forName(className);
        return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, key.substring(index + 1));
      } catch (final ClassCastException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // should not happen
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

Usage:
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws StreamWriteException, DatabindException, IOException {
    MyParamMap params = new MyParamMap();
    params.put(IntParam.I1, 1);
    params.put(DoubleParam.D2, 1.1);
    params.put(StringParam.S3, "sss");

    final Path path = Path.of("params.json");
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(path.toFile(), params);
    params = mapper.readValue(path.toFile(), MyParamMap.class);
    System.out.println(params);
  }


An enum and a map don't seem like the correct tools here (too many problems), I would try to redesign, if at all possible. Still, this can be achieved with wrapper class and custom serializer/deserializer for keys - applying mixin on Enum to achieve polymorphic serialization does not seem possible (do not take my word for it though, I may be wrong).
A wrapper for the enum:
@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = EnumWrapperKeySerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = EnumWrapperKeyDeserializer.class)
public record EnumWrapper(Enum<?> anEnum) {
}

Notice keyUsing, that's to make the de/serializers used specifically for map keys.
A deserializer to preserve information about the enum class and the instance:
class EnumWrapperKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<EnumWrapper> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(EnumWrapper value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    gen.writeFieldName(value.anEnum().getClass().getName() + "." + value.anEnum().name());
  }
}

A deserializer to parse to correct enum and instance of that enum:
public class EnumWrapperKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

  @Override
  public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
    int index = key.lastIndexOf(".");
    String enumName = key.substring(0, index);
    Class<? extends Enum> enumClass;
    try {
      enumClass = (Class<? extends Enum>) Class.forName(enumName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      //probably should not happen
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    String enumValue = key.substring(index + 1);
    return new EnumWrapper(Enum.valueOf(enumClass, enumValue));
  }
}

Example:
Map<EnumWrapper, Object> map = Map.of(
            new EnumWrapper(IntParam.I1), 1,
            new EnumWrapper(DoubleParam.D2), 1.0,
            new EnumWrapper(StringParam.S3), "sss");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String res = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println(res);
Map<EnumWrapper, Object> map2 = mapper.readValue(res, new TypeReference<>() {
});


Thank you for your answer. Why not using the same kind of serializer you suggest, but working directly on the original Map<Enum<?>, Object>? (I'll try this as soon as I get the chance).

@Sirion I believe it's not possible for Enum (might be wrong though), I was not able to achieve it with a mixin and could not figure out another working solution.

I solved the problem writing a custom deserializer that loads the JSON object in a HashMap<String, Object> and then loops through the different enum types looking for the enum instance with the same name as the key in the map (this relies on the fact that all enum instances have different names across all the involved enum types).
public class ConfigMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<Enum<?>, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<Enum<?>, Object> deserialize(
        final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt
    ) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      final HashMap<String, Object> rawObject = jp.readValueAs(new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});
      final HashMap<Enum<?>, Object> config = new HashMap<>(rawObject.size());

      for (final Entry<String, Object> entry: rawObject.entrySet()) {
        final String name = entry.getKey();

        Enum<?> param = null;
        try { param = IntParam.valueOf(name); } catch (final Exception e) { /* no-op */ }
        try { param = DoubleParam.valueOf(name); } catch (final Exception e) { /* no-op */ }
        try { param = StringParam.valueOf(name); } catch (final Exception e) { /* no-op */ }

        if (param == null) {
          // DO SOMETHING...
        } else {
          config.put(param, entry.getValue());
        }
      }

      return config;
    }
  }

Finally, I decorated the config property with
@JsonDeserialize(using=ConfigMapDeserializer.class) Map<Enum<?>, Object> config;

